# Is this the right setup so that everyone can talk to each other? (In same network LAN)

Tags: router, home-networking, modem, switch, unifi

I want to make sure if my setup will be functional.
Let me describe the diagram I made.

The HomeHub is my ISP modem hooked to Fiber and cannot be replaced.
There's an advanced option where I can enter the Mac address of my router to link as a bridge and then I can deactivate everything on the HomeHub (wifi, dhcp etc..)

The TP-Link Deco XE75 router will act as a DHCP and an AP too (it will connect to the internet with a PPPoE connection to my ISP so no double NAT). The fact that it's far from the ISP Modem, I added a switch so that it can talk to the modem and that I can add other connections. (I could run another cable from the Office to directly connect the modem to the TP-Link but don't want to do it if this setup works)

The switch in the closet is a managed Unifi switch and I have the controller with it. So basically can everyone talk to each other without conflict or is the WAN Modem connection will not recognize the router and the router won't be able to address IPs? Do I need to config VLAN or something?

Thanks for you help.

[image]

Comment: Is this setup driven by the WIFI AP functionality in the XE75 that you need for your Office?  I would disable  DHCP on the  XE75 and not the  HH4000.  How do you plan for the living room to access the internet if it is on the WAN side of the XE75?

Comment: I was thinking of using the XE75 as my main router with DHCP. Will the living room get an IP from Unifi Switch that will be connected with the XE75?

Comment: "I was thinking of using the XE75 as my main router with Dhcp" yes you communicated that. "Will the living room get an IP from Unifi Switch" No, it's a switch. US-8 won't give or receive dhcp. None of the devices in living room will use dhcp either. You didn't answer my question what is driving this configuration preference?  Save a lot of aggravation if HH4000 handles dhcp

Comment: This is the basic config.  You can add as many switches as you want.  XE75 left in as I presume you are using it for wifi: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G1zz.png)  edited on phone so apologies if a little crude.

Comment: "what is driving this configuration preference?" I prefer the TP-Link interface to manage all my network assets, plus a better range for the WiFi. But yeah, I could use the HH4000 as DHCP and managing all my stuff then use the XE75 as just an AP.

Comment: If you want to use the x75 as a router you need to locate it in the closet or have two cable runs from the closet to the XE75  (currently show 1)